Legend issue with Log10 scaling on ListContourPlot
I'm trying to ListContourPlot some data with a Log10 scale. I tried adapting the answer from this post (thanks azerbajdzan), but the legend and colors are screwy. I want the legend to show the Log10 of the list conttest and the colors to be the nice gradient defined by shadetest.
data={{6.016*10^(-7),8.744*10^(-7),9.639*10^(-7),1.017*10^(-6),4.474*10^(-7),1.024*10^(-7),1.683*10^(-8)},{0.00001173,0.000027,0.0000571,0.00008704,0.00004059,0.00001024,1.683*10^(-6)},{0.00006784,0.0005764,0.001103,0.002878,0.002796,0.0009125,0.0001683},{0.00184,0.003665,0.007431,0.05106,0.05266,0.04773,0.01451},{0.04977,0.09923,0.2016,0.4596,0.805,0.7214,0.5183},{1.346,2.684,5.455,12.45,21.81,17.01,7.523},{36.39,72.57,147.5,336.6,590.,459.9,205.}};

conttest={-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2}//Sort;
shadetest=Blend["M10DefaultDensityGradient",#]&/@Rescale[Append[conts2,Max[conts2]+1]];

ListContourPlot[data,ScalingFunctions->{None,None,"Log10"},Frame->True,DataRange->{{0,60},{0,6}},PlotLegends->Automatic,Contours->conttest,ContourShading->shadetest]



Remove ScalingFunctions and use Log10 straight on your data - data={...}//Log10

data = {{6.016*10^(-7), 8.744*10^(-7), 9.639*10^(-7), 1.017*10^(-6), 
    4.474*10^(-7), 1.024*10^(-7), 1.683*10^(-8)}, {0.00001173, 
    0.000027, 0.0000571, 0.00008704, 0.00004059, 0.00001024, 
    1.683*10^(-6)}, {0.00006784, 0.0005764, 0.001103, 0.002878, 
    0.002796, 0.0009125, 0.0001683}, {0.00184, 0.003665, 0.007431, 
    0.05106, 0.05266, 0.04773, 0.01451}, {0.04977, 0.09923, 0.2016, 
    0.4596, 0.805, 0.7214, 0.5183}, {1.346, 2.684, 5.455, 12.45, 
    21.81, 17.01, 7.523}, {36.39, 72.57, 147.5, 336.6, 590., 459.9, 
    205.}};

conttest = {-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2} // Sort;
shadetest = 
  Blend["M10DefaultDensityGradient", #] & /@ 
   Rescale[Append[conttest, Max[conttest] + 1]];

ListContourPlot[data // Log10, Frame -> True, 
 DataRange -> {{0, 60}, {0, 6}}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 Contours -> conttest, ContourShading -> shadetest]



